# Capture audio and upload it

Tags: javascript, audio, cordova, dropbox

I'm working on mobile device (iOS). I develop a hybrid application using HTML/CSS/Javascript.

I have this code founded on [Apache Cordova API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Audio</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Called when capture operation is finished
    //
    function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
        var i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
        }       
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    // 
    function captureError(error) {
        var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
        navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function captureAudio() {
        // Launch device audio recording application, 
        // allowing user to capture up to 2 audio clips
        navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 2});
    }

    // Upload files to server
    function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            path = mediaFile.fullPath,
            name = mediaFile.name;

        ft.upload(path,
            "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
            function(result) {
                console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            { fileName: name });   
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="captureAudio();">Capture Audio</button> <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can capture my voice with it and in theory upload it to

> http://my.domain.com/upload.php

But I wonder how to adapt this code to upload file on my Dropbox . Is it possible to upload file to Dropbox as easy as that ?

Answer (score 1):

As @sinaneker mentioned, you can do this server-side with PHP (or other languages).

But you can also do this directly from JavaScript using Dropbox's JavaScript library: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js